# Best phrase to invite user to choose one item

Tags: selection, wording

Users can create galleries and choose one to add to their profile. What's the best phrasing for this?

Below image shows item #1 has been selected (hence the color and the heart) and the mouse is hovering #2, showing a menu with the button `use this gallery`.

What would better phrasing be for `use this gallery`?

[image]

Comment: Can they only choose one? It looks like you can switch to select a different gallery instead, is that correct? And is there a submit or 'next' button once they choose?

Comment: @MikeM They can only choose one. There is no next button, the selected item gets colored and the heart overlayed. Basically the selected item will get the treatment of item #1 in above image.

Answer (score 1):

### Be clear regarding the already selected gallery. That can help indicate that only one is selectable, and that it's currently being used.

My opinion (no research!) is that what's more unclear is the fact that the gallery with the heart is actually being used. This arose because of what the icon could potentially communicate.

You're using the heart icon, which is often used to communicate 'I like this', not necessarily 'This is currently in use' (and is the only one being used).

The Nielsen Norman Group has some good resources re: icons and text labels for clarity:

From **Yes, icons need text labels:**

> Universal icons are rare. To help overcome the ambiguity that almost all icons face, a text label must be present alongside an icon to clarify its meaning.

[image]

There might be better phrasing for `use this gallery` (it actually seems fairly clear), but equally important is clear status indication about what's currently selected (and used).

Comment: Fully agree! The idea was already to change the heart into a green selection symbol.